# Auto delete disk using libcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

i'm trying to create a VM using libcloud with auto delete feature. The thing is that it only works for boot disks.

Example:

`new_node = driver.create_node("my_node_str", size, get_root_snapshot(driver), location,ex_service_accounts=sa_scopes, ex_disk_auto_delete=True, ...`

Then I attach a disk:

`driver.attach_volume(my_node,...,ex_boot=False, ex_auto_delete=True)`

So i go to GCE and this volume auto delete is turned OFF

So, i try to change it "manually" using libcloud:

`conn.ex_set_volume_auto_delete(vol, node)`

And I get the error :

`libcloud.common.google.GoogleBaseError: u"Invalid value for field 'disk': 'myvolume1-worker-disk'`

But the disk is created, attached and it is working on my VM.

Debugging libloud everything seems to be ok acording to documentation (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/setDiskAutoDelete):

It calls:

`u'/zones/us-central1-b/instances/myinstancename/setDiskAutoDelete'`

With parameters:
`'deviceName': volume.name, 'autoDelete': auto_delete,`
any clues?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be a bug with `attach_volume`. I'll do a bit of testing and get that fixed up if so.

Regarding using `ex_set_volume_auto_delete`, you need to pass in a `StorageVolume` object. It looks like you are just passing in a string (the name of the disk).

You could try,

```
disk_obj = driver.ex_get_volume('string-name-of-disk')
driver.ex_set_volume_auto_delete(node_obj, disk_obj, ex_auto_delete=True)
```

I'll follow up about the first issue when I look into it more.

Comment: I did find a bug with `attach_volume` and pushed a fix [dc4daee](https://github.com/apache/libcloud/commit/dc4daeef451988f55349e31993f1401770c530f6)

Comment: Thank you Eric,

I'll test the fix and review my code (i believe i'm not passing the string, but the object) ASAP.

Comment: Hi Eric,
I believe that my code is correct but the error persists:
`
    #size = get_node_size(driverGCE, zone, "n1-standard-1")
    conn = connect_gce()
    node=conn.ex_get_node("myinstance", "all")
    vol=conn.ex_get_volume("my-disk-worker-disk", "all")
    print vol
    print node.name
    print node.extra['zone'].name
    conn.ex_set_volume_auto_delete(vol, node)`

I get the error :

libcloud.common.google.GoogleBaseError: u"Invalid value for field 'disk': 'my-disk-worker-disk'. "

File "/drivers/gce.py", line 3460, in ex_set_volume_auto_delete

Comment: BTW, your fix worked when attaching a disk! Thanks again.